# Importing Xtend source file into Java project

Tags: java, xtend

I know that its possible to redefine operands with Xtend. My question is, can I redefine an operand using Xtend code and then import this source code into Java project to use it?

For example I would redefine the operand `+` with Xtend, than I import this source into my Java project and use the redefined operand. Is it possible?

Comment: If you want to know whether operator overloading from Xtend to Java is theoretically possible, you should update your question's title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create or copy an Xtend file into a Java project, then just open it, this will install the Xtend builder on the project. Now, you will have a problem marker on the first line of code, quick fix it with Ctrl+1, this will add the necessary Xtend libs to the classpath. That's all.

Source: the Getting Started section of [Xtend's installation instructions](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/download.html).

Note: as @rzymek [says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19953094/90874), you will be able to use the overriden operator only in Xtend, Java will only see the method `operator_plus`.

Comment: That means there`s no way to use overriden operator with Xtend in Java. Thank you.

Comment: If that really was your question, I encourage you to accept or at least upvote @rzymek's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't redefine operators in Java. You can in Xtend.
Xtend compiler will generate `e1.operator_plus(e2)` Java code, when you're calling an overriden `+` operator.